# How to get the auth token for dropbox directly into java program so that user don't need to copy paste it

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am developing an application where I have to upload file and download file from dropbox account, application is a java desktop application. I have used the sample code and was able to run it without any glitch. But I want to bypass that user needs to copy the auth code form browser to the application, how can be that done. I want my application to get the auth token directly into the application, because this is causing overhead on user.
All the experts please help me.
Here's the code I have Implemented.

```
import com.dropbox.core.*;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DbxException {
    // Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developers website.
    final String APP_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    final String APP_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

    DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("JavaTutorial/1.0",
        Locale.getDefault().toString());
    DbxWebAuthNoRedirect webAuth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(config, appInfo);

    // Have the user sign in and authorize your app.
    String authorizeUrl = webAuth.start();
    System.out.println("1. Go to: " + authorizeUrl);
    System.out.println("2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first)");
    System.out.println("3. Copy the authorization code.");
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(authorizeUrl));
    String code = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine().trim();

    // This will fail if the user enters an invalid authorization code.
    DbxAuthFinish authFinish = webAuth.finish(code);

    DbxClient client = new DbxClient(config, authFinish.accessToken);

    System.out.println("Linked account: " + client.getAccountInfo().displayName);

    File inputFile = new File("OpenCv_Video_display_link.txt");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    try {
        DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("/OpenCv_Video_display_link.txt",
            DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);
        System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }

    DbxEntry.WithChildren listing = client.getMetadataWithChildren("/");
    System.out.println("Files in the root path:");
    for (DbxEntry child : listing.children) {
        System.out.println("    " + child.name + ": " + child.toString());
    }

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("121verbs.pdf");
    try {
        DbxEntry.File downloadedFile = client.getFile("/121verbs.pdf", null,
            outputStream);
        System.out.println("Metadata: " + downloadedFile.toString());
    } finally {
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: We had some discussion over on the Dropbox developer forum about this: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=109542.

Comment: @smarx: I have gone through the discussion and am trying to replace the 
`DbxWebAuthNoRedirect webAuth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(config, appInfo);
` with DbxWebAuth but am facing problem while ` HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
 String sessionKey = "dropbox-auth-csrf-token";` I am unable to add this HttpSession, I tried downloading different jars for it. Please show me the way. Am stuck.

Comment: @smarx: When I type this `HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);` it shows me error in eclipse saying `request cannot be resolved`.

Comment: `DbxWebAuth` would only apply to web apps. `request` would need to be a reference to an HTTP request.

Comment: @smarx: So how can I use DbxWebAuth in my desktop app to bypass the copy paste of auth token from webpage.

Comment: You can't. Or rather, you can, but it involves turning your app into a web app (by embedding a web server in it). Definitely possible, but as you'll see on the thread on the Dropbox forum, I'm still trying to work out the security implications.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps
2. Click on the app. On this page under Outh 2, look for Generated access token.
3. Click on Generate.
4. This is your access token. This authenticates that the user is you and you don't have to go through the standard authorization flow everytime.

I have commented the unnecessary code, you will only need the last line.

```
/* // Have the user sign in and authorize your app.
String authorizeUrl = webAuth.start();
System.out.println("1. Go to: " + authorizeUrl);
System.out.println("2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first)");
System.out.println("3. Copy the authorization code.");
String code = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine().trim();

// This will fail if the user enters an invalid authorization code.
DbxAuthFinish authFinish = webAuth.finish(code); */

String accessToken = "Your access token goes here";
```

Answer (score 1):

Based in this example [from dropbox blog](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/04/dropbox-authorization-in-a-windows-forms-app/) i made this example in java it will open a Webview where you can introduce your dropbox credentials after that dropbox will redirect you and the redirection url will have the token then we get the token from the URl and print to the console.

```
    public class AnotherClass extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(new com.sun.webkit.network.CookieManager());
        launch(args);
    }

    //This can be any URL. But you have to register in your dropbox app
    final String redirectUri = "https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver";
    final String AppKey = "YOUR APP KEY ";
    final String url = "https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=" + AppKey + "&response_type=token&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage pStage) throws Exception {

        Stage primaryStage = pStage;
        primaryStage.setTitle("Dropbox Sign In");


        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.load(url);
        webEngine.locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> arg0, String oldLocation, String newLocation) {
                try {
                    if (newLocation.startsWith(redirectUri)) {
                        ArrayMap<String, String> map = parseQuery(newLocation.split("#")[1]);
                        if (map.containsKey("access_token")) {
                            System.out.print("Token: " + map.get("access_token"));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.getChildren().add(webView);

        Scene rootScene = new Scene(stackPane);

        primaryStage.setScene(rootScene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    ArrayMap<String, String> parseQuery(String query) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        ArrayMap<String, String> params = new ArrayMap<String, String>();
        for (String param : query.split("&")) {
            String[] pair = param.split("=");
            String key = URLDecoder.decode(pair[0], "UTF-8");
            String value = URLDecoder.decode(pair[1], "UTF-8");
            params.put(key, value);
        }
        return params;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my development experience on Android platform, you may insert JavaScript code to scan the web page and extract the auth code, like below :

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(final WebView webView, final String url) {

    if (AUTHORIZE_SUBMIT_URL.equalsIgnoreCase(url)
            && AUTHORIZE_SUBMIT_TITLE.equalsIgnoreCase(webView.getTitle())) {

        webView.loadUrl("javascript:HtmlViewer.showHTML"
                + "('<html>'+document.getElementById('auth-code').innerHTML+'</html>');");
    }
}
```